# Angularjs) selecting entire number upon focusing on input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input with `type=number` which I want to have the entire number selected upon the user touching the input. How would I go about doing this?

I'm getting errors that `type=number` doesn't support selection - I'm finding this difficult to get around. If anyone can handle this in terms of an Angularjs directive, that would be ideal.

Thanks,

Comment: Change the input type from number to text and then handle the selection and any input restrictions yourself. Perhaps you could use regex to restrict only numeric characters.

Comment: this sounds more like an issue with the way that input type=number is handled by client devices than an issue with angular or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try using input `type="tel"`. It may have been fixed I've never gone back to explore but at one point in time Angular and `type="number"` did not combine well at all.

It has to do with the way the browser handles its own processes and a collision with Angular doing the same.